# Integrating models and views in new Sinatra extensions

Tags: ruby, model, view, sinatra

So I would like to use the new possibility to create extensions for [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com).

My Extension needs to integrate a model and some views/templates but I don't know how to or where to integrate them?

Did anybody already built something more complex than the example from the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/wild.html#libs) is a list of libraries and extensions on the Sinatra web site

Comment: Not exactly what I need but thanks for the tip. Haven't seen that list yet.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [Sinatra: Writing Extensions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html) article on the official Sinatra website.